# How to optimize execution plan for lopsided table

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, sql-server-2019, statistics

I've got a table with an index that's pretty lopsided, where a small number of values has a much higher count of rows than most of them. In the table there are a few hundred million rows - my index is on a given column, where there are generally a couple dozen rows that match a particular value, but there are a few hundred values that have thousands and even tens of thousands of rows. This seems to throw off the stats and mess up execution plans.

To illustrate:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test1] (
    [ID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    ,[SomeKey] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
    ,[SomeValue] INT NOT NULL
);
GO

CREATE INDEX [IX_SomeKey_Covering]
ON [dbo].[Test1] ([SomeKey])
INCLUDE ([SomeValue]);
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Add 200,000 unique SomeKey values in there:
;WITH q AS (
    SELECT TOP 60 1 [A] FROM sys.objects
), q1 AS (
    SELECT NEWID() [A], 1 [B]
    FROM q AS q1
    CROSS JOIN q AS q2
    CROSS JOIN q AS q3
)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test1] ([SomeKey], [SomeValue])
SELECT TOP 200000 [A], [B]
FROM q1;

-- Add 2000 SomeKey values that have 1000 rows each
DECLARE @i INT = 0;
WHILE @i < 2000
BEGIN
    SET @i += 1;

    DECLARE @SomeKey UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID();
    ;WITH q AS (
        SELECT TOP 32 1 [A] FROM sys.objects
    ), q1 AS (
        SELECT 1 [A]
        FROM q AS q1
        CROSS JOIN q AS q2
    )
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test1] ([SomeKey], [SomeValue])
    SELECT TOP 1000 @SomeKey, @i
    FROM q1;
END;

GO
```

This creates a table where there are 200,000 values that only match a single row, and then 2,000 values that each match 1,000 rows. So about 99% of the possible values only have one result.

Now I'll query it two ways - one just looking for a single value, and one that has 1,000 values to look up:

```
DECLARE @SomeKey UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID();
SELECT [SomeValue] FROM [dbo].[Test1] WHERE [SomeKey] = @SomeKey;

-- #tmp table has 1,000 unique values
SELECT [SomeValue]
FROM [dbo].[Test1] t
JOIN #tmp tmp on t.[SomeKey] = tmp.[SomeKey];
```

The first index seek thinks there are 75 rows that will be returned:

[image: estimated execution plan]

It of course multiplies on the second query, where it thinks it's going to return 75,000 results:

[image: estimated execution plan]

If I rebuild the index and try again, it drops down to 10 instead of 70, but that's still problematic, and after more inserts, it creeps up again.

Ideally I'd like it to think that there's a small number of results per match, since that's the 99% case, and if it's occasionally wrong, it can spill over memory or do whatever else it needs to.

Is there something I can do to the statistics, or the index, or the query, to accomplish that?

Comment: Your first query is falling victim to a [local variable](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/yet-another-post-about-local-variables/).

Comment: You should upload the actual execution plans to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan) and link them in your post. It's much better to analyze than a screenshot.

Comment: Also lot of good relevant information in Erik's linked post.^ Was contemplating on suggesting Dynamic SQL for branching, myself. But do you need to use a variable in your real use case? Just curious, does `UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.Test1 WITH FULLSCAN` improve your issue at all?

Comment: @ErikDarling Thanks - as many articles as I read about the parameter sniffing issues and optimizing differently, it still flies above my head every time. I'll read your post a few dozen more times and see if it clicks. And I've been trying to get my work to pay for some SQL performance training for nearly a year now, but I may just give up and buy your videos myself.

Comment: @J.D. Running UPDATE STATISTICS by itself doesn't change the plan, but WITH FULLSCAN did have the same effect as rebuilding the index - the estimation went from 70-something to 10. Seems that shouldn't be too harmful, so maybe that could be a quick solution.

Comment: Index rebuilds are a wasteful operation anyway. But they effectively trigger a few other good things to occur such as causing new statistics to get generated (which you can just do directly). The `WITH FULLSCAN` option causes SQL Server to analyze the entire Table (or index if you specify a particular index) as opposed to just sampling a subset of the data like the default call to `UPDATE STATISTICS` does without options specified. You can also specify what the sampling percent to use should be by specifying the option `WITH SAMPLE SomeInteger PERCENT` (replace SomeInteger with your own).

Comment: @J.D. Cool, thanks. Still learning all that about stats, but that makes sense - I can see how small random sampling could miss this kind of thing but would be close to perfect for evenly distributed data.

Comment: No prob! I kinda ran out of comment space before, but basically the reason I mentioned the option for `WITH SAMPLE SomeInteger PERCENT` is because sometimes using the entire Table as the sampling size is not the best either. Some people sometimes find a sweet spot with some sample size in between. You can play around with less percentages, of e.g. 80%, 50%, etc and see if you get even better estimates after. Your mileage may vary though, and `FULLSCAN` might just be the best option in your case.